# utop installation using opam fails in fedora 25

Tags: ocaml, utop

I have an error installing utop in fedora 25 when I run "opam install utop". The first time I ran the command some packages were installed, but not all. I ran the same command again and got the error message below. Any suggestion?

```
The following actions will be performed:
  - install lambda-term 1.12.0                          [required by utop]
  - install utop        2.0.2 
===== 2 to install =====
Do you want to continue ? [Y/n] y

=-=- Gathering sources =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[lambda-term] Archive in cache
[utop] Archive in cache

=-=- Processing actions -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[ERROR] The compilation of lambda-term failed at "jbuilder build -p lambda-term
        -j 4".

#=== ERROR while installing lambda-term.1.12.0 ================================#
# opam-version 1.2.2
# os           linux
# command      jbuilder build -p lambda-term -j 4
# path         /home/se/.opam/4.05.0/build/lambda-term.1.12.0
# compiler     4.05.0
# exit-code    1
# env-file     /home/se/.opam/4.05.0/build/lambda-term.1.12.0/lambda-term-1999-58c514.env
# stdout-file  /home/se/.opam/4.05.0/build/lambda-term.1.12.0/lambda-term-1999-58c514.out
# stderr-file  /home/se/.opam/4.05.0/build/lambda-term.1.12.0/lambda-term-1999-58c514.err
### stderr ###
# Warning 3: deprecated: module Lwt_sequence
# [...]
# File "src/lTerm_widget_callbacks.ml", line 48, characters 2-21:
# Warning 3: deprecated: module Lwt_sequence
#  This module is an implementation detail of Lwt. See
#    https://github.com/ocsigen/lwt/issues/361
#       ocamlc src/lTerm_unix.{cmo,cmt} (exit 2)
# (cd _build/default && /home/se/.opam/4.05.0/bin/ocamlc.opt -w -40 -safe-string -g -bin-annot -I /home/se/.opam/4.05.0/lib/bytes -I /home/se/.opam/4.05.0/lib/camomile -I /home/se/.opam/4.05.0/lib/lwt -I /home/se/.opam/4.05.0/lib/lwt_react -I /home/se/.opam/4.05.0/lib/ocaml -I /home/se/.opam/4.05.0/lib/ocaml/threads -I /home/se/.opam/4.05.0/lib/react -I /home/se/.opam/4.05.0/lib/result -I /home/se/.opam/4.05.0/lib/zed -no-alias-deps -I src -o src/lTerm_unix.cmo -c -impl src/lTerm_unix.ml)
# File "src/lTerm_unix.ml", line 342, characters 32-51:
# Error: This expression has type bytes but an expression was expected of type
#          string



=-=- Error report -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
The following actions were aborted
  - install utop 2.0.2
The following actions failed
  - install lambda-term 1.12.0
No changes have been performed
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem fixed:

```
opam update
opam upgrade
```

and possibly

```
opam reinstall [whatever-was-not-installed-correctly]
```